# OpenMP ` invalid controlling predicate` when "parallelizing" more than one for loops

Tags: c, openmp

I 'm trying to create a parallel block in openMP with multiple for loops inside. What I've done so far (or at least the important parts i guess, i can post the whole program if neccessary):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main(int argc, char**argv) {

  [...]

  int i, j, N=200, num_t=2;

  [...]
  M = (int) round(M);
  [...]
  double **u = malloc(N * sizeof(double));
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    u[i] = (double*) malloc(M * sizeof(double));
  }

  /* Initialize time and space arrays */
  double *x, *t;
  x = (double*) malloc(N * sizeof(double));
  t = (double*) malloc(M * sizeof(double));
  
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(num_t) private(i,j) shared(x,t,u,dt,dx,N,M,c) default(none)
  {
#pragma omp for 
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    x[i] =  0 + i * dx;
 
#pragma omp for 
  for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    t[i] = 0 + i * dt;

  /* Initial Conditions */
  #pragma omp for
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    [do stuff with `u` array]
  }
  /* boundary conditions. */
  #pragma omp for
  for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
    [more stuff with `u` array]
  }

#pragma omp for collapse(2)
  for (j = 0; j< M - 1; j++) {
    for(i = 1; i < N - 1; i ++) {
      [even more stuff with `u` array].
    }
 }
}
```

And why I try to compile this with `gcc -Wall -fopenmp  -fsanitize=address exe1.c -o t1_1 -lm`

I get the following error

```sh
exe1.c:56:15: error: invalid controlling predicate
   for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
               ^
exe1.c:67:15: error: invalid controlling predicate
   for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
               ^
exe1.c:73:15: error: invalid controlling predicate
   for (j = 0; j< M - 1; j++) {
```

The only way I 've managed to actually compile this, is by ending the parallel block (not sure if this is the correct terminology) after the first `#pragma omp for`:

```c
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(num_t) private(i,j) shared(x,t,u,dt,dx,N,M,c) default(none)
  {
#pragma omp for 
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    x[i] =  0 + i * dx;
}
```

My gcc version is `gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` and openMP `#define _OPENMP 201511`.

Now, I 've read lots of posts here about this error comming up (`invalid controlling predicate`) but most of them seems to come from not conforming to a "Canonical Loop Form". Think my code does conform. What could be the issue?
Thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting errors in loops involving `M` probably because `M` is not of an integer type. A clue in favor of that assumption is that you are rounding its value at some point:

```
M = (int) round(M);
```

You cannot use floating-point variables in canonical loop forms. So this doesn't work:

```c
#pragma omp for 
  for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    t[i] = 0 + i * dt;
```

but this should work:

```c
#pragma omp for 
  for (i = 0; i < (int)M; i++)
    t[i] = 0 + i * dt;
```

Comment: Yup! That's correct. I am quite new to C tbh and I thought that by casting the value of a variable would change it's type too. In any case I still can't understand the limitation behind not allowing comparisons between int and double (or others) with openMP

Comment: The problem is not the comparison per se but the requirement that the number of iterations should be able to be determined in advance. The standard forces you to do the cast yourself and bear any architectural specifics this might entail.